# c++ microcontroller global classes/singelton?

Tags: c++, microcontroller

I am currently using C++ on a microcontroller and I am having an issue where I don't know what the proper implementation is:

I am for example using an serial interface class which takes care of configuring the serial port (setting baud, data bits...). Since I only want to do it at the initialization phase of my MCU at the start, I don't know how to handles this with classes.

Shall I make a global class/singleton which I create at the initialization phase (in this way I can keep my serial parameters) or shall i create a class everytime I need to use the serial interface (but this would reopen my serial line - or do I leave the constructor empty)?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I try to avoid global variables and singletons.

I defined a class with a constructor that accepts a pathname and configuration to open the port, and a destructor that closes the port.  Then, I declared a `static` local instance of it in `main(...)` and I passed references to it in to the constructors of other classes that needed to use the port.

Passing the reference around (as opposed to declaring a global instance, or a global function to get a singleton) is what enabled me to write unit tests for the other classes in which the tests passed in a references to [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) serial port objects.

Comment: I like this approach *thumbsUp*.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for opinions because all options are valid.
I do believe creating a singleton to store the configuration and resources needed is a good approach. This way you can implement RAII idiom, and gain easy access when needed.

Comment: True, it is more like a design question. I guess my goal was to see different opinions and evaluate them. Thanks for the quick response!